# $ ng g s services/data --module=app.module

Tags: angular

the above code is not working and showing the following error Unknown option: '--module'.
I've even tried it without '=' and '.module' and it still not working.

Comment: please provide error message.

Comment: There is no such an option https://angular.io/cli/generate#service just run `ng g s services/data`

Comment: You cant specify modules for `ng g s` but you can specify `project`